# How execute php file in command line?

Tags: php, cmd

I have 1 file php: `C:\\Xml2InDesign\\InDesignTagConverter.php`

I exe it by:

```
$sjis_cmd="php \"C:\\Xml2InDesign\\InDesignTagConverter.php\";
exec($sjis_cmd, $output);
```

It not working. What do i must setting?

I run from cmd:

```
php "C:\Xml2InDesign\InDesignTagConverter.php" "c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\\direction.xml" "c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\\tables"
```

Show error: `'php' is not recognized...`

Comment: Do you want to execute the php file from within php? Why do you want to do that? Instead use include/require and call the functions you need.

Comment: What does it mean "not working". Do you have an error? a warning? Is something written in $output?

Comment: I only has command exe in log file. I copy exe on cmd . it show error as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your php.exe path and run command from there.

Like if your php.exe is in `C:\PHP5\php.exe` , then you can execute like this

```
C:\PHP5\php.exe "C:\\Xml2InDesign\\InDesignTagConverter.php\"
```

Refer this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php)

**OR**

if you want to run it through php code then use [exec](https://www.php.net/function.exec) command

Answer (score 1):

```
The PHP CLI as its called ( php for the Command Line Interface ) is called php.exe It lives in c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.exe ( where x and y are the version numbers of php that you have installed )

If you want to create php scrips to run from the command line that great its easy and very useful.

Create yourself a batch file like this, lets call it phppath.cmd :

PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y php -v

Save this into one of your folders that is already on your PATH, so you can run it from anywhere.

Now from a command window, cd into your source folder and run >phppath.

Then run

php your_script.php
```